# Beginner Guide to OpenGL in Xcode

Tags: objective-c, swift, xcode, opengl

I am currently trying to learn Open GL, but I am finding it very difficult just to get started. I have zero OpenGL experience, but a little experience in Obj-C and Swift. I only wish to draw basic geometry to start with, nothing fancy.

I first assumed you could use NSOpenGLView.. but there seems to be no helpful documentation on how to actually get started with this. I have searched and searched, but for as a newcomer all the documentation and tutorials are very hard to work with, and very often they are out of date etc

I just need a basic starting point of a OpenGL view within a view controller that I can begin with.

Comment: This is pretty broad. You should show a specific example that you're having problems with.

Comment: Hmm by its nature it's a broad question. Seems like a comment for the sake of a comment.. which isn't helpful

Comment: No, because overly broad questions are offtopic. Your question will likely be closed unless you narrow it down. "How do I approach this topic" questions aren't appropriate for the site as they're almost entirely opinion based. If you got a start and had an issue with something specific, that would be ontopic.

Comment: Well my problem is. I need to create an OpenGL view which I can then use to practice OpenGL. Whether I do this using NSOpenGlView or some other framework or library I don't really care. I just need some way of approaching the problem because as I said, the documentation I have been coming across is often outdated or too complicated. Do you have any experience in Xcode/OpenGL yourself?

Comment: Nope. But someone else on this site does. If you make the question more appropriate, they'll be more likely to help you. This isn't me attacking you or trying to shut you down. Overly broad, open ended questions like this don't get good answers as readily. Experienced users spend their time answering questions that the site is made for: smaller, searchable, specific questions. If you really do want to ask an open ended question like this, a discussion medium like Reddit or Google+ would be a better place to start.

Comment: I wouldn't know where to start writing an answer. For this question its (in my opinion) impossible to answer with just a few paragraphs.

Comment: My 5 start site with several GitHub repositories is http://www.flexmonkey.com - be aware that the focus is on iOS, GLKView, and CoreImage, but check out Simon's *Filterpedia* app. The custom filters use GLSL code inside CoreImage kernels. (His iBook, CoreImage for Swift is also excellent.)  Of course, you should download GPUImage2 and study that code - it's well known. Finally, a quick search on "Swift OpenGL example" returned a ton of hits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have encountered the same problem a few years ago when trying to learn OpenGL for an action game I was creating. However, as I dug deeper into the documents and tutorials, I had concluded that it was way more complicated than I thought. Here is some of the information I learned:

1. OpenGL is not the same is OpenGL ES, and OpenGL ES on Xcode is also different from that on android since Apple have modified some of the syntax.
2. OpenGL ES on Xcode has a couple of different versions:

- `ES1` (fixed pipeline): Does not require shader programs. It's more simple but has fewer options.
- `ES2`/`ES3` (programmable pipeline): Uses `shader` and have more options, but is more complicated.

After that I changed platform to using Windows as an alternative, since tutorial of OpenGL on PC is more detailed and many sample projects can be found. The basics are much more easy to learn compared to using Xcode.

I suggest that you learn the basic concepts of drawing shapes as well as programming shaders on another platform such as `Windows`, and then come back to Xcode after you have more experience.

If you insist on using Xcode, though, I can provide some sample code that can be compiled successfully without errors. The following code is written on OpenGL ES1. Just create a new `Single View Application` and paste the following code:

ViewController.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <GLKit/GLKit.h>

@interface ViewController : GLKViewController

@end
```

ViewController.m:

```
#import "ViewController.h"

typedef struct {
    
    GLKVector3 PositionCoordinates;
    
}VertexData;

#define SQUARE_SIZE 120.0f

VertexData Vertices[] = {
    
    {0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f},
    {SQUARE_SIZE, 0.0f, 0.0f},
    {0.0f, SQUARE_SIZE, 0.0f},
    {0.0f, SQUARE_SIZE, 0.0f},
    {SQUARE_SIZE, 0.0f, 0.0f},
    {SQUARE_SIZE, SQUARE_SIZE, 0.0f}
};

@interface ViewController ()

@property (nonatomic, strong) EAGLContext *Context;
@property (nonatomic, strong) GLKBaseEffect *BaseEffect;

@end

@implementation ViewController {
    
    GLuint _VertexBufferID;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    
    self.Context = [[EAGLContext alloc] initWithAPI:kEAGLRenderingAPIOpenGLES2];
    
    GLKView *View = (GLKView *)self.view;
    View.context = self.Context;
    [EAGLContext setCurrentContext:self.Context];
    
    self.BaseEffect = [[GLKBaseEffect alloc] init];
    self.BaseEffect.useConstantColor = YES;
    self.BaseEffect.constantColor = GLKVector4Make(255/255.0f, 255/255.0f, 255/255.0f, 1.0f);
    
    self.BaseEffect.transform.projectionMatrix = GLKMatrix4MakeOrtho(0, self.view.bounds.size.width, 0, self.view.bounds.size.height, 0, 100);
    
    glClearColor(0/255.0f, 0/255.0f, 0/255.0f, 1.0f);
    
    glGenBuffers(1, &_VertexBufferID);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, _VertexBufferID);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(Vertices), Vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(GLKVertexAttribPosition);
    glVertexAttribPointer(GLKVertexAttribPosition, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(VertexData), NULL);
}

#pragma mark - GLKView delegate methods

-(void)glkView:(GLKView *)view drawInRect:(CGRect)rect {
    
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    [self.BaseEffect prepareToDraw];
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 6);
}

-(void)Update {
    
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

If you're using `Storyboards`, remember to change the view on the ViewController into a `GLKView` class, as shown in the photo.

[image: Change view class into GLKView]

Compile, and then, BOOM! A juicy white square is ripe and ready to be edited!

[image: White square in GLKView]

I'd burst into tears the first time I succeeded with this code. Modified it from some code I learned form a Youtube tutorial. Gotta thank that guy if I ever see him again. Hope this helped you :)

P.S. I have a copy of the sample code of 'OpenGL ES3 Template Project` with two 3D cubes rotating each other, but that's a lot more complicated.

Comment: This is just what I needed, thank you very much for the all the advice and sample code!

Comment: If you like this answer, you can mark this as accepted :)